# Issue in Facebook SignIn

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using Facebook Sign In in my app. I have pods to import dependencies. I have used pod `FBSDKCoreKit` and pod `FBSDKLoginKit` in pod file.

And my code is

//AppDelegate

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKi

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //Realm migration
    realmMigration()
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
    navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = UIColor.darkGray

    let landingViewObj = LandingView(nibName: (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? "LandingView" : "LandingView"), bundle: nil)
    navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: landingViewObj)

    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true

    FIRApp.configure()

    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    return true
}

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
    -> Bool
{
    let facebookDidHandle = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: "UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey", annotation: [:])

    let googleDidHandle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                            sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                            annotation: [:])

    return googleDidHandle || facebookDidHandle
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool
{

    let facebookDidHandle = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url as URL!, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

    let googleDidHandle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                            annotation: annotation)

    return googleDidHandle || facebookDidHandle
}
```

In my ViewController,

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
```

In my facebook login custom button action,

```
 @IBAction func facebookSigninAction(_ sender: Any)
{
 let graphRequest:FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"first_name,email, picture.type(large)"])

        graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                let data:[String:AnyObject] = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                print(data)

            }
        })
 }

func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError?)
{
    if let error = error
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
    // ...
}
```

And in the plist file I have added the following things

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>349152685470803</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fb</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
</array>
 <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>facebook</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb349152685470803</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
<string>com.googleusercontent.apps.316518738586-d36rr39tpllb40056330jrra12v1tn86</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

My prob is i get the following error in my log and the app does not call the closure in which i could fetch the result.

```
2017-01-11 17:10:21.047 MyApp[7525:1384017] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
```

Is there any another way I could request for permissions and read the result object?

Comment: Had the same problem. add bundle identifier in settings. So in facebook settings I added a platform "IOS" and gave my bundle id there and it worked for me.

Comment: @Cliffordwh I have did it already. Still didnt work.

Comment: Make sure you have FacebookDisplayName in your plist file. Also double check the bundle Id! ( case sensitive )

Answer (score 0):

[image]You need to Add Bundle Id Like This.

```
<dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>*** Add BundleId</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string> fb349152685470803 </string>
        </array>
```